# Finding the mode of a sorted array using bin search

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, search, mode

Hi there i've been tasked with Writing a simple program that is given an array of integers and determines the mode, which is the number that appears most frequently in the array.

The approach i'm trying to adopt is using a bubble sort with a bin search algorithm my level of knowledge is at a beginner stage can someone help point me?

Where i'm going wrong i believe it to be passing the correct search value to find it in the array! But i maybe wrong but some help would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance for those to take time to try help me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int arrayLength = 10;
int searchVal;
int numGroup[arrayLength];

bool isSorted(int [], int arrayLength);
int binSearch(int [],int arrayLegth,int searchVal);

int main()
{
 // Take in num
 for (int index = 0; index < arrayLength; index++)
 {
    cout << "Enter Number: ";
    cin >> numGroup[index];
 }


// Sort numbers

//var to hold the val being swaped
int swapHolder = 0;

//bubble sort 
for (int iSort = 0; iSort < arrayLength; iSort++)
{
 for (int jSort = (iSort + 1); jSort <= arrayLength - 1; jSort++)
    {

        if (numGroup[iSort] > numGroup[jSort])
        {
            swapHolder = numGroup[iSort];
            numGroup[iSort] = numGroup[jSort];
            numGroup[jSort] = swapHolder;
}

  }
  }
//passes the sorted array and the length to the isSorted 
isSorted(numGroup, arrayLength);


return 0;
}

bool isSorted(int numGroup[], int arrayLength){

cout << "Final result" << endl;

for (int index = 0; index < arrayLength - 1 ; index++)
{

    if (numGroup[index] > numGroup[index + 1])
    {
        cout << "it's false";
        system("pause");
        return false;
    }
    cout << numGroup[index] << endl;

    //cout << arrayLength << endl;
}
cout << numGroup[arrayLength - 1] << endl;
//trying to make searchVal
for (int i = 0; i < numGroup[arrayLength - 1]; i++)
{
    if (numGroup[i] == numGroup[i])
    {
        int searchVal = numGroup[i];
    }

}
binSearch(numGroup, arrayLength, searchVal);
cout << "It's true ";
system("pause");
return true;

}

int binSearch(int numGroup[], int arrayLength,int searchVal){

int low = 0;
int high = arrayLength - 1;

int mid;
    while (low <= high)
    {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        //search through the array 
        if (searchVal == numGroup[mid])
        {
            return mid;
        }
        else if (searchVal > numGroup[mid])
        {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            high = mid - 1;
        }

    }
    cout << "In bin search " << mid;
    return mid;
}
```

Comment: You may replace your buble sort by `std::sort`.

Comment: There is nothing to search. Count the length of each repeating number sequence of the sorted array, then find the longest.

Comment: I have tendency to over complicate problems/task think this can be solved in a more easy/simpler way

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to sort the array. You can have another array (**freq**) which will count the numbers appearances. So, a mini code for that:

```
int myArray[10];
int freq[1000]; //we assume that the numbers are smaller than 1000

void count()
{
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
     ++freq[v[i]];
  }
}

int ReturnModeElement()
{
   int maxFreq = -1;
   int element = -1;
   for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; ++i)
   {
      if(freq[v[i]] > maxFreq)
      {
         maxFreq = freq[v[i]];
         element = v[i];
      }
   }

  return element;
}
```

I hope you got the idea :)

Comment: Thanks but i'm not a 100% sure of whats going on within you code. I think i can follow but not 100% sure, as i eluded to before my knowledge is at a beginner level

Comment: In that code you just count the numbers of appearances of each element and then select the maximum one from that appearances.